# Blender is saving a single object into multiple meshes

Tags: mesh, unity

I'm trying to import a blender file into unity. I am saving the file with a single object as .blend and .obj, but whenever I try to import into unity, it shows multiple mesh objects being merged into a single object, and I can only work with one, since each mesh has its own texture. I have tried selecting all and joining objects, but that doesn't seem to work.

What can I do for blender to save a single mesh?

In blender
[image: Blender]
In unity
[image: Unity]

Comment: How many vertices do you have?  It might be possible that Unity is splitting the object into multiply ~65000 vertex chunks.

Comment: A lot... Is there anything I can do to make this work without having to remodel?

Comment: Unity should just handle it.  Give the same material (in Unity) to each part of your object.  If you want to decrease vertices (which I think you can do without messing up the UV unwrap), get rid of unnecessary vertices.  Like, do you *really* need (I'm guessing here) the ~1000 vertices going around the leg (?) in the screen shot.  Remember, games are real-time, you need to model for that.

Comment: Regarding format, try FBX instead of obj or blend file. A blend file might fail. And the obj importer of Unity is flawed. It's not longer supported and updated since Unity version 3. FBX is the official supported file format for Unity.

Comment: The problem with giving the same material is that it is copied, which is not what I want. If I have, for example, a drawing in the material, it will appear twice in the model. Also @Tiles Aug I did not know that. That is some useful information. Thanks.